# Renaming a file on a network share using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

So I have a SQL job setup to delete a file, then copy the latest, and then the last step is to rename it. The code works fine if I run it directly in a powershell window. However as a job step it fails. It's set to run as the same user that's used for the delete and copy steps. It has full control on the path. The error in the job history just says: 'Invalid Path: '\1.1.1.1\Backups\DB01_PROD_FULL_01252016.bak'.' Which is what $myfile below ends up being.

```
$mypath='Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\1.1.1.1\Backups\'
$myfile=gci $mypath | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 -ExpandProperty FullName
Rename-Item -path $myfile -newname 'DB.bak'
```

Comment: My guess is there is an issue with the copy completing before you try to name. Why not get rid of the rename-item command and rename the file during the copy-item command.

Comment: Not sure where you have the powershell code, but is the backslash an escape character?  It seems like you are missing a backslash in your path in the error message.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks Sean. That worked perfectly....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming the item during the copy-item command was the answer. Thanks Sean!